# Spring REST with Multiple Databases

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mongodb, spring-rest, spring-profiles

We have a Spring REST application which supports multiple databases. Our REST APIs are on SQL Server but few of the clients are on MongoDB and MySQL. We have to implement our DAO layer in such a way that it support all 3 databases.

We have defined 3 spring profiles - mssql , mongodb and mysql. The default profile would be mssql. We have also provided 3 different datasources for these profile.

Our Approach : We are providing 3 different implementations of our DAO interface. If StaffingDao is an interface then we have implementation like this:

```
 @Profile("mssql")
 public class StaffingDAOMSSQLImpl implements StaffingDao

 @Profile("mongodb")
 public class StaffingDAOMongoImpl implements StaffingDao

 @Profile("mysql")
 public class StaffingDAOMySQLImpl implements StaffingDao
```

Is it good approach?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As you have different databases you need different approach to get the data into 1 single format, which you can pass to you business layer, so according to me this approach is valid and will work.

Answer (score 0):

`@Profile` is a valid approach.

Another approach can be to have `@Conditional` bean initialization. May be something like this

```
@ConditionalOnResource(resources = "classpath:mysql.properties")
@Bean(name="staffingDao")
public StaffingDao staffingDao(){
   return new StaffingDAOMySQLImpl();
}
```